# Which data format can be used with both QGIS Desktop and Android?

Tags: qgis, android

My data is in MS Access geodatabase(creating with ArcGIS). I want use Qgis desktop and Qgis android (and dropbox)

1. Is it required to convert my mdb file to another format? (Qgis on Android can't read my mdb file)
2. Which format should I use?

Comment: i don't think it's a similar question: It's not about fgdb but Personal Geodatabase and about alternative storage types which will also run on android! In the provided link, i couldn't find any answer on these questions.

Comment: shapefile will work on both.

Comment: @Mapperz Would KML work at all or is it too limited?

Answer (score 2):

I think Spatialite would probably be the best option. For vector data I've used quite large Spatialite databases in QGIS Android.

N.

Answer (score 1):

Shapefiles and GeoTiffs are very standard formats and should work on both.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be spatialite and mbtiles when using a 2.0 nightly. This formats are the fastest performing.